# IntelliJ structural search to find self-closing HTML tags

Tags: html, intellij-idea, structural-search

Right now, I do not want to haven self-closing tags in my html files while programming on IntelliJ.

So basically, I would IntelliJ to spot the following code snippets as a warning:

```
<img src='foo.png' />
<br />
```

I am trying to determine if I have any self-closing tags using structural search on IntelliJ. I tried to use the following code:

```
<$tag$ />
```

Where the text constraint of `$tag$` is `[a-zA-Z]`.

However, it matches with almost every tag in my file. Is there a way to just highlight the two examples I have illustrated?

Comment: SSR might be an overkill for this simple case. Did you try Find in Path with the `<.*/>` regex? You may also limit the scope to specific HTML files.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I would like to use the regex as a inspection, but I do not think IntelliJ has that as an option. Is there a way to use pure regex as an inspection?

Comment: I tried doing creating a structural search template with `$tag$` where text/regexp is defined as `\<[a-zA-Z]+.*/\>`. It should capture `<br/>`, but it did not capture it in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structural Search & Replace is actually not designed for this kind of thing. It searches for code patterns, and ignores style. However the desired behaviour can be achieved with a hack. To start use the following pattern:

```
<$tag$>
```

This will match all tags, self closing or not. Don't add a `text constraint`, but use a `script constraint` with the following Groovy script text:

```
tag.parent.text.endsWith("/>")
```

Now the pattern should find all tags ending in `"/>"`.

Comment: Thanks, I want to learn how to use script constraint more properly. Do you know any good sources that teaches you this?

Comment: Sorry, no. There are some more examples under the structural-search tag here on stackoverflow you may want to check out for examples. Script constraints basically allow to access IntelliJ IDEA internals. Here I used the HTML PSI api (which is an abstract syntax tree) to query the source code. A familiarity with this api helps a lot. However every language has its own psi although there are many similarities. Fully describing script constraints would probably fill a pretty thick book.